# Add active class to parent node in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
const sounds = [
   {
     key: 'Q',
    mp3: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3',
     title: 'Title Q'
  },
  {
     key: 'W',
    mp3: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-2.mp3',
    title: 'Title W'
  },
  {
    key: 'E',
    mp3: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-3.mp3',
    title: 'Title E'
  },
  {
     key: 'A',
    mp3: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-4_1.mp3',
    title: 'Title A'
  },
  {
    key: 'S',
    mp3: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-6.mp3',
    title: 'Title S'
  },
  {
   key: 'D',
    mp3: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Dsc_Oh.mp3',
    title: 'Title D'
  },
  {
    key: 'Z',
    mp3: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Kick_n_Hat.mp3',
    title: 'Title Z'
  },
  {
    key: 'X',
    mp3: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/RP4_KICK_1.mp3',
    title: 'Title X'
  },
  {
    key: 'C',
    mp3: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Cev_H2.mp3',
    title: 'Title C'
  }
]

const keys = ['Q','W','E','A','S','D','Z','X','C'];

const App = () => ( 
 <div id='drum-machine' className='container'>
        <div id='display' className='display'>
          <h1> Title </h1>
          {sounds.map((sound, idx, title) => (
          <Box text={sound.key} key={idx} audio={sound.mp3} title={sound.title}/>
          ))}
        </div>
    </div>
);
 
class Box extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.audio = React.createRef();
  }
  playSound = () => {
    this.audio.current.play();
    window.document.querySelector('h1').innerText = this.props.title
  }
  

  
  render() {
    const {text, audio} = this.props
    return (
       <div className='drum-pad' onClick={this.playSound} id={`drum-${text}`} >{text}<audio ref={this.audio} src={audio} className='clip' id={text}/>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
 
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  {/*sur l'appui d'une touche je crèe un id égale à la key, si cet id correspond à ce lui de audio, je joue l'audio */}
  const id = e.key.toUpperCase();
  const audio = document.getElementById(id);
 
  if (audio) {
    const parent = audio.parentNode;
    parent.classList.add('active');
    audio.play();
    
    {/*Lorsque la touche est relachéé, la touche repasse en affichage normal.
    audio.addEventListener('ended', () => {
      parent.classList.remove('active')
    })*/}
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,300;1,400;1,700;1,900&display=swap');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #9b59b6;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.container { /* container de l'App id 'drum-machine' */
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 380px;
}
.display { /* container des touches */
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 360px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.display h1 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.drum-pad { /* touche */
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #8e44ad;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  
  /* Alternative pour centrer les lettre:
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center; 
  */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'><div>
```

This is my codepen link: Deleted !!
I added all my code. It's works in the preview window.

I try to add an 'active' class on a div element with the className='drum-pad'. But this doesn't work, I don't know why. At the end of JavaScript code, take a look to the addEventListener.

Ps : I don't know why but I edit my message for correct it and I can't submit it.  A message ask me "more details". So I add some text just for that. Someone can say me what the pb exactly for my futurs post ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/) *(not my downvote)*

Comment: The code you do have in the question looks like it would work, assuming you actually have elements whose `id` values match the names of keys. So there must be more to this, which an [mre] would make clear.

Comment: _But_ you shouldn't really be using `getElementById` with React.

Comment: I added code in snippet

Comment: That was a fun question to answer @bob17. Hope it helps.

Comment: Andy, thanks for your code. I will study it. But this doesn't help me to fix the pb in my code. I don't want to remake all now. After I will try to do it in other way but for now I would like to fix my pb.

Answer (score 0):

If you save the state of the drum in `App` you can then pass that prop down to the Box component. The Box component can decide whether to immediately play the sound, or wait for a click.

But the most important thing is to [use `useEffect` to set up the `keydown` event on the window](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), and allow React to drive the code.

I also reduced your CSS code down by using [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid).

```js
const { useEffect, useRef, useState } = React;

const sounds=[{key:"Q",mp3:"https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3"},{key:"W",mp3:"https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-2.mp3"},{key:"E",mp3:"https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-3.mp3"},{key:"A",mp3:"https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-4_1.mp3"},{key:"S",mp3:"https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-6.mp3"},{key:"D",mp3:"https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Dsc_Oh.mp3"},{key:"Z",mp3:"https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Kick_n_Hat.mp3"},{key:"X",mp3:"https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/RP4_KICK_1.mp3"},{key:"C",mp3:"https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Cev_H2.mp3"}];

// Passing in the sounds into the App component
function App({ sounds }) {

  // Creating an initial state with an array of
  // keys from the sounds object set to false
  const state = sounds.map(obj => ({ [obj.key]: false }));

  // Set that state
  const [ isPlaying, setIsPlaying ] = useState(state);

  // The useEffect sets up the keydown event on the window
  // When a key is pressed the state is updated, and a render takes place
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
      setIsPlaying({ ...isPlaying, [e.key.toUpperCase()]: true });
    });

    // Clean up
    return function () {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown');
    }

  }, []);

  // So now we're passing the property (key)
  // of state down to the Box component
  return (
    <div className="container">
      {sounds.map((sound, idx) => (
        <Box
          text={sound.key}
          key={idx}
          audio={sound.mp3}
          isPlaying={isPlaying[sound.key]}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

function Box({ text, audio, isPlaying }) {

  // Still using `ref` but I've changed this to
  // a function component so now we use `useRef`
  const ref = useRef();

  // Play the sound
  function playSound() {
    ref.current.play();
  }

  // If `isPlaying` is true play the sound
  if (isPlaying) playSound();

  // Otherwise wait for the click event on the
  // div and then play the sound
  return (
    <div
      className="box"
      onClick={playSound}
      >{text}
      <audio ref={ref} src={audio} />
    </div>
  )

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App sounds={sounds} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  background-color: #8e44ad;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0.2em;
  padding: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```